# Shouldn't I be able to access a method from sub class?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

**I have a 2 part question**
part 1.) Im doing a polymorphism exercise and the base class is Car and one of my sub classes is titled MustangGT97. I created a method in MustangGT97 called mustangIgnition(); however I cannot see or access that method in the main and I need help understanding why?

[image]

[image]

part2.) My second question is upcasting the right term to use when you create an instance like this----> ParentClass a = new ChildClass(); also when creating an instance of an object like this -----> ChildClass ab = new ChildCLass(); WOuldnt (a) and (ab) do the same thing?

Comment: `a` is of type `Car` and doesn't have the method `mustangIgnition`

Comment: You can always access parent class methods using the child class instance. The reverse is not possible. However you can always cast it to child class instance and use the method. `MustangGT97 mustang = (MustangGT97) a; mustang.mustangIgnition()` will now be accessible

Answer (score 0):

For your questions, refer to the answers below :

1. In your example, the base class is `Car`.
   Because you are taking the reference of base class and it doesn't contain method which you have defined in the sub-class, you aren't allowed to call it until you explicitly cast the object to the sub-class type.
2. Refer to the code below for example :

   ```
   Car car = new MustangGT97(...);
   MustangGT97 mustangCar1 = (MustangGT97) car;

   // And writing like this
   MustangGT97 mustangCar2 = new MustangGT97(...);
   ```

From the above example, you can see that explicitly casting the object from parent to subclass or directly using the reference type of subclass gives the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** The variables `a`, `b` and `c` are of type `Car`, therefore you only have access to fields and methods of this parent type. Therefore, `a` won't have access to `mustangIgnition`, `b` won't have access to `dodgeIgnition` and so on.

You're looking at the problem from a wrong angle. `Car` is a super type and defines behaviour that is common to all child types, for example `ignition`. Therefore you need to have such a method in `Car` and have all child classes `Override` this method, in order to have implementation specific behaviour:

```
public abstract class Car {
    // ... fields and constructor omitted

    public abstract void ignition();
}

public class MustangGT97 extends Car {
    // ... fields and constructor omitted

    @Override
    public void ignition() {
        // do something specific here
    }
}
```

Note that I made the super type and the method `abstract`. This leaves the implementation details to all child classes but forces every car to have an `ignition` behaviour.

Now when doing something like this:

```
Car[] cars = createCarArray();
for(Car car : cars) {
    car.ignition();
}
```

you can be sure that every implementation of `Car` has an `ignition` method without actually knowing which implementations there are.

Or in your case you can do now:

```
a.ignition();
```

And it will call the specific implementation of your `MustangGT97` class.

**2)** No, `ParentClass a = new ChildClass();` is not called "upcasting". If `ParentClass` were an interface, you'd probably hear the term "programming to an interface" (I don't recall if there's a set term for when you just assign to some arbitrary parent type, or if it's called the same then).

Upcasting is the act of *casting* to a type higher in the hierarchy. For example:

```
MustangGT97 m = new MustangGT97(...);
Car c = (Car) m;
```

Here you're *upcasting* your specific implementation to the more general type. This always works, since `MustangGT97` is a child class of `Car`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain in depth!

Comment: @ClaudeManbodh no problem. I you felt it helped you, you can tick the check mark on this answer. Then others will know that this answer has solved your problem.